# Django 2 : How can I use a template path with user.id without crashing if not logged?

Tags: django, django-templates

I need to create a profile edit link in my Django Home template.

Like this :

```
<a href="{% url 'app:profile' user.id %}">{{ user.displayed_name }}</a>
```

But it crashes when no user is logged...

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'profile' with arguments '(None,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['profile\/(?P[0-9]+)\/$']

Is there a way to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the template if tag. `{% if user.id %}` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#if

Comment: Thank you! I tried with {{ user }} and it didn't work but with {{ user.id }} it works!!

Comment: You can also use `user.is_authenticated` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated

Comment: I recommend to use `user.is_authenticated` over if user.id tag. It will check if the user is logged in or not. If user is logged in then the id is the default column in the table.